# Mass delete Debug logs using Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, delete, debug, debug-logs, bulk-delete

In my developer sandbox the Apex logs count has exceeded beyond its limit and there are more than 1 lakh records created in it. I want to mass delete them, but not able to do so.

I am using the windows machine, and tried running the below commands to achieve the same.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" | out-file -encoding utf8 out.csv
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

But I am receiving an error in the console saying

```
ERROR running force:data:bulk:delete:  InvalidBatch : Records not found
```

Can anybody please let me know what am I doing wrong, and whether this can be achieved by any other ways.

Comment: I run the query you have listed via the Salesforce Developer Console's "Query Editor" on the org, click the first entry in the results, scroll to the bottom, shift-click on the last entry (to select all entries) and click the "Delete Row" button then wait while the entries are slowly deleted (takes longer for more entries).

Comment: Hey Phil, I tried doing the same too. But what I noticed is, even though it shows me as 2000 rows selected, when I hit the delete it deletes not more than 100 records at a time. Also it takes a lot of time to delete around 1.5 lakhs of records. So was trying to find a work around for the same.

Comment: No argument there - it is clunky and slow. We'll see if someone responds with a better way!

Comment: Is csv file empty? One other thing I would do is try using the csv file using dataloader and see if it works? This most likely seems like a encoding issue on windows. I use a similar command on MacOS and it works.

Comment: @javanoob The csv file isn't empty. Do the dataloader supports ApexLogs object? As the windows has UTF-8 formatting, i have changed the command accordingly. But still no luck.

Comment: @AkshayVasu Because we are not using useToolingApi Flag with the command, I am guessing it might be available with Dataloader also, though I have not tried.

Comment: @AkshayVasu  Also, try with other encoding types like “utf8BOM”, “utf8NoBOM”.. I see several other encoding options here that powershell supports: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" | out-file -encoding oem out.csv
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

With other encoding like utf8,utf16 etc SFDX was uploading a file with header only no -values,so it was giving error `running force:data:bulk:delete:  InvalidBatch : Records not found`

Comment: And that worked. Thank you! @Pmanglani

Answer (score 6):

The following worked fine for me in MAC

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" --resultformat csv > out.csv

sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

I have not tried on windows but the commands above should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mohith, but In windows it's not working. May be because of the format issue. It's still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The force:data commands are now deprecated - although not gone yet.
A more up-to-date version is:

```
sfdx data query --query "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog " -r "csv" > ApexLogsToDelete.csv
sfdx data delete bulk --sobject ApexLog --file ApexLogsToDelete.csv
sfdx data delete resume --use-most-recent
```

The 'resume' command is just there so you can monitor your job. --use-most-recent is a shortcust though, to using the actual job Id - if another job starts, you'll get the wrong batch. But, when you run the data delete bulk command, it does tell you the command to view the actual batch in SF

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sfdx-hardis](https://github.com/hardisgroupcom/sfdx-hardis#sfdx-hardisorgpurgeapexlog--z--d---websocket-string--u-string---apiversion-string---json---loglevel-tracedebuginfowarnerrorfataltracedebuginfowarnerrorfatal) command to delete all logs of an org

```
sfdx hardis:org:purge:apexlog
```

If you are not connected to an org, it will prompt you for one

This command is also available in [VsCode SFDX Hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) menu **Debugger**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The following worked fine for me in Window VS Code. Please run these two commands:

```
 1. sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" | out-file -encoding oem out.csv`

 2. sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one: https://github.com/osieckiAdam/osiecki-sfdx-plugins. This is a small plugin created by me, but it does its job well.

To run a delete job and track the progress, use the following command:

```bash
sfdx oa:apex:log:delete
```

To run a delete job asynchronously and get the SFDX command to track the progress, use the -a flag:

```bash
sfdx oa:apex:log:delete -a
```

If you want to delete only your debug logs, use the -m flag:

```bash
sfdx oa:apex:log:delete -m
```

To delete debug logs created by any user/users, use the -c flag followed by the user names of the users:

```bash
oa:apex:log:delete -c -n test1@user.org,test2@user.org
```

To delete debug logs with specified statuses, use the -s flag followed by the statuses in double quotes:

```bash
sfdx oa:apex:log:delete -s "Internal Salesforce.com Error,success"
```

You can install this plugin using the standard install command for plugins:

```bash
sfdx plugins:install osiecki-sfdx-plugins
```

And rest assured, it works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.